# Improper Integral for $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-ikx}}{x}dx$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to see if the following integral is solvable:

$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{e^{-ikx}}{x}dx$

I think, if the bounds were $\int_{\infty}^\infty$, then you can draw a Contour with pole at z = 0 and solve it from there using Jordan's Lemma, but what about when the lower bound is 0? How does this affect the calculation?  Does this value even converge?

Thanks!

Comment: Strictly speaking the integral doesn’t exist as it behaves like $1/x$ as $x\to0^+$. Perhaps there was a wider context in which you saw this, that *is* solvable

Comment: What does exist is $\int_0^\infty\Im\frac{e^{-ikx}}{x}dx$, but not $\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-ikx}}{x}dx$ or $\Im\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-ikx}}{x}dx$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think, if the bounds were $ \int_{\infty}^{\infty} $, then you can draw a Contour with pole at z = 0 and solve it from there using Jordan's Lemma, but what about when the lower bound is 0? How does this affect the calculation? Does this value even converge?

Nice idea to solve this, but it won't help here,
'cause the value don't even converge aka it's not solve'able...

**How to show that this isn't solv'able**

But the integral is not solvable!

First we have to form the antiderivative:
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \frac{e^{-\mathrm{i} \cdot k \cdot x}}{x}\\
F(x) &= \int \frac{e^{-\mathrm{i} \cdot k \cdot x}}{x} ~ \mathrm{d}x\\
u &:= \mathrm{i} \cdot k \cdot x \rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x}
 = \mathrm{i} \cdot k \rightarrow \mathrm{d}x = - \frac{\mathrm{i}}{k} ~ \mathrm{d}u\\
F(x) &= -\int -\frac{e^{-u}}{u} ~ \mathrm{d}u \quad\mid\quad \operatorname{E}_{1}(u) := \int -\frac{e^{-u}}{u} ~ \mathrm{d}u\\
F(x) &= -\operatorname{E}_{1}(u) \quad\mid\quad u := \mathrm{i} \cdot k \cdot x\\
F(x) &= -\operatorname{E}_{1}(\mathrm{i} \cdot k \cdot x)\\
F(x) &= -(-\gamma - \ln(\mathrm{i} \cdot k \cdot x) + \operatorname{Ein}(\mathrm{i} \cdot k \cdot x))\\
F(x) &= \gamma + \ln(\mathrm{i} \cdot k \cdot x) - \operatorname{Ein}(\mathrm{i} \cdot k \cdot x))\\
\end{align*}
$$

(with $ \operatorname{E}_{1}(x) $ as the Exponential integral from one to infity)

No we can use the integral limits:
$$
\begin{align*}
F(x) &= -\operatorname{E}_{1}(\mathrm{i} \cdot k \cdot x)\\
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\mathrm{i} \cdot k \cdot x}}{x} ~ \mathrm{d}x &= \lim_{{x} \to {\infty}} (\gamma + \ln(\mathrm{i} \cdot k \cdot x) - \operatorname{Ein}(\mathrm{i} \cdot k \cdot x))) - \lim_{{x} \to {0}} (\gamma + \ln(\mathrm{i} \cdot k \cdot x) - \operatorname{Ein}(\mathrm{i} \cdot k \cdot x)))\\
&\Rightarrow \text{while } \arg(\ln(x \cdot k \cdot i)) \text{ is periodic to } 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \text{ it's not convergeting!}\\
&=\Rightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\mathrm{i} \cdot k \cdot x}}{x} ~ \mathrm{d}x \text{ does not converge and isn't defined}\\
\end{align*}
$$